# Mule Service Proxy

Tags: service, proxy, mule

im trying to proxy a Sevice using Mule 3.4 but one thing still not working...

my config:

```
<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https"
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.4/mule.xsd
   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.4/mule-http.xsd
   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.4/mule-pattern.xsd
   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.4/mule-spring-security.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
        name="memory-dao" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>

<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user name="asdf" password="asdf" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>

<!-- http:connector name="NoSessionConnector">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:connector-->

<pattern:web-service-proxy name="serviceName"
      inboundAddress="http://localhost:8050/newService"
      outboundAddress="http://remoteHost/servicos/v2/service.svc" 
      wsdlLocation="http://remoteHost/servicos/v2/service.svc?Wsdl"/>
```

But that way i get the original WSDL file and not a converted with the new localhost, what can i do to change it so who ever uses the service will not know where it si or how to access it...

Tks for any help in advance!

Comment: Does the WSDL at `http://remoteHost/servicos/v2/service.svc` contain exactly this address: `http://remoteHost/servicos/v2/service.svc` in the `soap:address` elements?

Comment: yes it does... i need a way for this localhost point to the remoteHost direct so any application connecting to the localhost doesnt get the address of the remoteHost... Any idea?

Comment: So the localhost will have almost the same WSDL but with the local adress forwarding to the remoteHost...

Comment: Then it must be a bug because URL rewriting of `soap:address`es is a main feature of the `pattern:web-service-proxy` and I don't understand why it doesn't work for you. Can you try removing `wsdlLocation`? The proxy should automatically add "?wsdl", fetch an rewrite the WSDL.

Comment: Cause of some specification from microsoft i need to change it to use ?singelWSDL, the ?WSDL will not work properlly in some scenarious, its a frangmented version and need to be a single file to be able to use on every system, i will do a test using what you said but even so i still need to forward a single file...

Comment: In the configuration shown above you have `?Wsdl` not `?singleWSDL`. Anything else that's different? To be able to help we need accurate information. Also, is this service internal or can it be reached externally? Being able to test you help too.

Comment: Ok David got this thing working and now i got the problem... the file WSDL came with the remoteHost adress but ive pointed as ip Adress not the same name adress that came with the WSDL file, when i chaged to the name itself on the configuration file i was able to get it working the way i expect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address rewriting only works if you consistently use the same host name or IP address in the `outboundAddress` and `wsdlLocation` attributes, otherwise Mule can not detect it's the same source and rewriting will not happen.